# Alert to close child windows before form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, new-window

I have a table data in a form and there is dynamic link in each row which opens an external link in a new window (new browser tab). These rows are in n numbers with dynamic id.

What I need here is,when user try to submit the table details, they must close all the child windows. If any child div is still opened and if he tries to submit the form, it should given alert to close the child windows

Here is the sample **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JpDhX/2/)** of the form

```
<form>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td>SC1</td>
            <td><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">this is an external link</a></td>

<tr>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td>SC2</td>
            <td><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">this is an external link</a></td>

            <tr>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td>SC3</td>
            <td><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">this is an external link</a></td>
</tr>
    </table>
            <input type="submit"  value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: by child windows you mean the new browser windows opened through the external link?

Comment: you better create, open and close the window yourself

Comment: Record the state in the related element object. Something like this: `this.isTabOpen`. where `this` is the clicked element.

Comment: @Mr_Green but how will she know whether the opened windows has been closed by the user or not?

Comment: @rps https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onbeforeunload?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.onbeforeunload

Comment: @Mr_Green so basically set a flag on `newWindow.onbeforeunload` and if the the flag is not set on submit call `newWindow.alert('this window needs to be closed')e.preventDefault()`

Comment: @rps ya whatever :D. I have just shown the ending points. you can imagine however you want. which suits you best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store each opened window in an array and perform a check for open windows when the user tries to submit the form:

```
var windows = [];
$('a').click(function () {
    var myWindow = window.open(this.href);
    windows.push(myWindow);
});

$('form').submit(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < windows.length; i++) {
        if (!windows[i].closed) {
            alert('Close all windows before continuing');
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/JpDhX/5/)**

Comment: Nice one.. but is this good if there are more than 100 rows as OP specified?

Comment: @Mr_Green Well I think we should ask if the user is supposed to open all 100 windows

Comment: lolzz thats a valid point. First of all, it will crash the system.

Answer (score 1):

looks like you need to keep track of open windows and close them on submit

```
var windows = [];
$('a').click(function(){
    var win = window.open($(this).attr('href'),"_blank");
    windows.push(win);
});
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function(){
    if(windows && windows.length > 0)
        $.each(windows,function(index,el){
            el.close();
        });
});
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JpDhX/4/ you can use

Answer (score 0):

Have a js function call `window.open()` to create the new windows . Keep track of the references created.

Also , the code as you provided in the demo doesn't guarantee the links are opened in new windows.

relevant fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/DS83p/

Answer (score 0):

```
1.Instead of <a href> use onclick javascript:window.open.
2.Give title to the window.
3.For closing
  if (document.title === "the title you want") {
    window.close();
  }
4.Give the above code in button Click.
```

Comment: But there are more than 100 rows so I cant check based on  title. Also I dnt window to be closed automatically. It should just give an alert msg saying that new window is still opened

Comment: Try this instead. http://thisiswhatiknowabout.blogspot.in/2012/02/how-to-close-child-windows-when-closing.html